# Service Fabric - Remoting Listener and Communication Listener not working simultaneously

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I'm a newbie on Service Fabric and, im my exercises, I've done a Reliable Stateless Service that, in RunAsync, increments his attribute "counter". I verified that I can expose via interface IService a method that returns this counter values (method called from a client via ServiceProxy), obviously overriding CreateServiceInstanceListeners and adding CreateServiceRemotingListener.
Then I tried to add another custom communication listener SS1ServiceEndpoint (that listen on a specified port 7080):

```
<Endpoint Name="RemoteListener" />
<Endpoint Name="SS1ServiceEndpoint" Protocol="http" Port="7080" Type="Input" />
```

but the service throws initially

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in Microsoft.ServiceFabric.FabricTransport.dll
```

Then the OpenAsync method of the custom listener is called more and more times and after each call another exception is thrown:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Fabric.FabricElementAlreadyExistsException' in 
System.Fabric.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in 
Microsoft.ServiceFabric.FabricTransport.dll
```

If I remove CreateServiceRemotingListener in CreateServiceInstanceListeners, the service starts and I can call it from browser on the listening port.

My question is: are multiple listeners not supported? I've not tried with two custom listeners (on different port).

Answer (score 6):

Multiple listeners are supported, but you have to provide a name for the listeners, which is otherwise optional. Try adding a name for your listeners in your `CreateServiceInstanceListeners`.

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
    return new[]
    {
        new ServiceInstanceListener(context => this.CreateServiceRemotingListener(context), "RemotingListener"),
        new ServiceInstanceListener(context => new CustomListener(), "CustomListenerName")
    };
}
```

Comment: Great! It solves my problem :) From MSDN documentation it wasn't so clear!
Just another question: in this way can I expose a real WebAPI contained in the same project or is it better to separate the stateless service project from the WebAPI project?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can add a WebAPI in the same service. The decisions wether you put it in the same service or not depends on your design. Keep in mind that you are using a microservice architecture. If your WebAPI would only return the counter you should add it to the same service (WebAPI acts only as endpoint for counter). If your WebAPI has a lot of functionality, one of which is to return the counter, create a different service for it and get the counter using service remoting (Counter is a part of something bigger).

Comment: Completely agree with it not being clear, I missed that overload too when I was playing with multiple listeners!

Comment: @WouterB in the context of the question => "CustomListenerName" should be actually "SS1ServiceEndpoint" in ServiceInstanceListener constructor ?